# Nginx returning 499 error when browser closed before getting response for request

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We are facing 499 error when we close the browser tab before getting response for the request. We are using nginx in k8s.

I have tried by configuring "proxy_ignore_client_abort: on" property in ingress configuration, still we are getting issue even after configuring the above property. Please suggest me way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we are supposed to know that the nginx throw 499 if the client actively disconnected the connection. So it you may not pay much attention to it if everything is good.

Nginx could be the server to the user and the client to the backend server like the below:
from user->->nginx->server(tomcat).

In my case, I found that server like tomcat would abort the connection if it cannot handle too many requests in the accepted list.(or too slow to respond).

In tcp, the real server like tomcat would maintain 2 list. The first 1 is SYN list, and the 2nd is accepted list. Pls let me ellaborate it:

1. Clients firstly send syn to the server.
2. and the server put it into syn list and return SYN+ACK.
3. Client send the ACK to the server.
4. Finally the server established the connection after removing it from the syn list and put it into the accepted list.

In your case, if you close the tab before step2, I think you needn't do anything at all.

if you close the tab before the tab 4, you can refactor the interface of your server to be async to greatly enhance its responding speed.